# how to store the two variable in 2d array add array pass passing ajax requset

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to store the pair of the data in 2d array something like that.

```
 var items = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];
```

my already try this one

```
let ot_array = [];

$(document).on('click', '.overtime_send', function() {

  $('#employee_table tbody tr').each(function(row, tr) {

    var emp_no = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var ot_hours = $(tr).find('input').val();

    ot_array.push(emp_no,ot_hours);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'otrequset_action.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { user : ot_array },

      success: function(output){
        alert(output);
      }
    });

  });

});
```

this i already try but data is not coming.what is error of the my program and what is best way to it it?

Comment: `ot_array.push([emp_no,ot_hours]);` The item is `Array` type.

Answer (score 0):

you just need a simple push logic with separate array.

```js
var z= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    var j=1;
   var arr= z.map(function(){ var k=[];k.push(j);k.push(j+1);j=j+2; return k;})
  console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```